# Trying to use CSS to color negative numbers red

Tags: html, css

I only know very basic CSS and HTML and so I watched a few tutorials on how to accomplish this but it seems I must be doing something wrong as my HTML page is not loading how it should (negative numbers as red).

Css sheet:

```
    body
    {
    }
    TD[negative^="-"]:after {color:red;}

    table.classname td[negative^="-"]:after {color:red;}
```

HTML Sheet:

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet1.css"
    </head>
```

Sample row from table:

```
    <table class="classname" style="width:100%">
    <td negative=>-98669</td>
    </table>
```

Edit: My link attribute didn't have closing '>'.

Comment: I don't know how to post HTML without the HTML being read in the Question:  <td negative=>-98669</td>

Comment: The `=` makes no sense there. It would have to be `<td negative>` or `<td negative="somevalue">`. But you should not invent your own HTML attributes. Either use a custom data attribute (`data-negative="…"`), or use a class instead.

Comment: use a data-attribute like data-negative="true", then in css you can use td[data-negative=true]: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes . Or, even better, give the tds class="negative".

Comment: Are you in control of the `table` markup? Can you change the attribute `negative` to `data-negative="true"` or `class="negative"`?

Comment: also, why are you using the `:after` pseudo-element? You actually want the number inside the `<td>` to be red, right?

Comment: This is achievable with JS, would you accept an answer with that?

Answer (score 6):

If you generate special attribute on server side when value is negative you should use the data- attribute .

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

example:

```css
[data-negative] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>555</td>
    <td data-negative>-555</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the text turn red if minus sign in a `<td>` in a `<table>`.

I put this code in a JS-file and import it.

Then all my `<td>` that contains a minus sign becomes red:

```
function MakeNegative() {
    TDs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i=0; i<TDs.length; i++) {
            var temp = TDs[i];
            if (temp.firstChild.nodeValue.indexOf('-') == 0) temp.className = "negative";
        }
}

MakeNegative();
```

So the file contains both the function and a call to the function MakeNegative(), I tried some other stuff, but this worked on first try exactly how I wanted it.

The function puts the class-name "negative", then it is easy to controll it from a css-file by:

```
.negative {
   color: red;
   }
```

I thank Scott Hanselman who taught me this on his blogg.